# model A references model B on two fields (but one to one) in prisma

Tags: database-design, prisma

Each FileUpload should have exactly one "parent" ProjectDraft.

Each ProjectDraft should have two different optional fields that each can reference one FileUpload.

If I'd do it in raw SQL, I'd probably have two fields on the ProjectDraft, each being optional and referencing one FileUpload (via id).

This is my current schema:

```
model ProjectDraft {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  name      String

  heroImage             FileUpload?
  otherImage            FileUpload?
}

model FileUpload {
  id             String       @id @default(cuid())
  fileKey        String       @unique
  projectDraft   ProjectDraft @relation(fields: [projectDraftId], references: [id])
  projectDraftId String       @unique
}
```

`prisma format` originally wanted to make a `ProjectDraft ProjectDraft[]` array field (one-to-many that is, I think) on the FileUpload model, but that wouldn't be what I want (this would allow a FileUpload having no parent or more than one parent).

For my current schema, `prisma format` says:

```
Error validating model "ProjectDraft": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `heroImage` and `otherImage` in model `ProjectDraft` both refer to `FileUpload`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>).
```

I can add relation names for the ProjectDraft fields, but those two relations end up being the same one on the FileUpload (since each FileUpload should have only one parent).

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I am missing a basic concept here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a relation name if you want to refer more than one field to other model.

```prisma
model ProjectDraft {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String

  heroImageFileUploadId  String?
  otherImageFileUploadId String?
  heroImage              FileUpload? @relation("FileUploadHeroImage", fields: [heroImageFileUploadId], references: [id])
  otherImage             FileUpload? @relation("FileUploadOtherImage", fields: [otherImageFileUploadId], references: [id])
  FileUpload             FileUpload?
}

model FileUpload {
  id                      String         @id @default(cuid())
  fileKey                 String         @unique
  projectDraft            ProjectDraft   @relation(fields: [projectDraftId], references: [id])
  projectDraftId          String         @unique
  ProjectDraftHeroImages  ProjectDraft[] @relation("FileUploadHeroImage")
  ProjectDraftOtherImages ProjectDraft[] @relation("FileUploadOtherImage")
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense for me, each FileUpload is only part of exactly one ProjectDraft. In your example, each FileUpload has a relation to two ProjectDrafts.